# Cannot seem to subtract mirrored cylinders from a cube

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm fairly new to blender but have used 3d modelling programs before, and I've become baffled by a fairly simple problem.

I'm trying to model a pool table and I'm building the table bed.

I make a cube the right dimensions, and placed a cylinder at one corner.

I used modifiers to mirror the cylinder to four corners:

[image: Cube and cylinders]

As I understand it, I should then be able to add a boolean modifier to the cube to subtract the cylinders, but I just can't seem to make it work.  I can subtract the cube from the cylinders, leaving 4 cylinders with the cube corners chopped out, but nothing seems to work the other way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either you need to do every cylinder for itself, or you connect them with vertexes, then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you applied scale to both the objects?? If so then Select the cube then apply boolean modifier.Add Cylinder mesh under object and Select Difference operation and then apply the modifier.It should give you the desired result.[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong, I started over and used the steps above and it worked. (Edit, I think I might have applied it the wrong way around first, leaving a chunk out of the cylinder, then trying to make it work the other way, with no effect....)